# how to upload huge files in python requests?

Tags: python-2.7, api, streaming

I have a file with **4GB** size. I can not upload it with requests (`memory error`) . 
So, I searched about it and found a solution.

Here is my code:

```
m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={'username': username, 'password':password,'path': path,
            'new_file': (filename, open(filename, 'rb'), 'text/plain')}
)
req = requests.post(url, data=m, headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})
```

But it only upload `4MB`.